# How to add object to array that is located inside of another array using useState - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am wondering how do I push an object to an array that is located inside to another array, using useState.
below is my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();

export const Provider = ({children}) =>{

  const [categories, setCategory] = useState([
    { title: 'Personal' , id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999), notes: [
      { noteTitle: 'stam', 
        noteContent: 'stamstamstam',
        id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999)
      },
      { noteTitle: 'stam2',
        noteContent: 'stamstamstam232323',
        id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999)
      }
    ]},
    { title: 'Work' , id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999), notes: []},
    { title: 'Shopping' , id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999), notes: []}
  ]);

  const addNoteForCategory = (name, content, categoryId) => {
    const chosenCategory = categories.find((category) => category.id === categoryId)  
    setCategory([...chosenCategory.notes, {
      noteTitle: name, 
      noteContent: content, 
      id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999)
    }])
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` and change the item you want to change, then update the state.

```
const updatedCategories = categories.map(category => {
    if (category.id === 123) {
        return {
            ...category,
            notes: [
                ...category.notes,
                { title: 'Note 2' }
            ]
        }
    }

    return category;
});

setCategory(updatedCategories);
```

You need to replace the dummy ids and data that I used with your specific data.

Answer (score 0):

```
const addNoteForCategory = (name, content, categoryId) => {
      setCategory( prevState => {
        const chosenCategory = prevState.find((category) => category.id === categoryId);
        chosenCategory.notes.push({
          noteTitle: name, 
          noteContent: content, 
          id: Math.floor(Math.random()* 99999)
        });
        return prevState
    });

  }
```